# What's the best practice for taking MySQL dump, encrypting it and then pushing to s3?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, encryption, amazon-s3

This current project requires that the DB be dumped, encrypted and pushed to s3. I'm wondering what might be some "best practices" for such a task. As of now I'm using a pretty straight ahead method but would like to have some better ideas where security is concerned. Here is the start of my script:

```
mysqldump -u root --password="lepass" --all-databases --single-transaction > db.backup.sql
tar -c db.backup.sql | openssl des3 -salt --passphrase foopass > db.backup.tarfile
s3put backup/db.backup.tarfile db.backup.tarfile
# Let's pull it down again and untar it for kicks
s3get surgeryflow-backup/db/db.backup.tarfile db.backup.tarfile
cat db.backup.tarfile | openssl des3 -d -salt --passphrase foopass |tar -xvj
```

Obviously the problem is that this script everything an attacker would need to raise hell.

Any thoughts, critiques and suggestions for this task will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

first you can create a 'user' in mysql that has read-only permissions for the database in question, that would reduce potential destructive damage, were an attacker to gain access to your backup script.

then you could use `gpg` or `pgp` encryption on your backup before or after you compress it, and you can do that without needing to provide a password, using your public key.

and of course, you should `chmod 700 backupscript.sh` to prevent anyone from reading your password.

there may be other ways to do passwordless database snapshots, but i'm not aware of any off the top of my head.

`gpg` or `pgp` seems like a superior alternative to the `openssl` method you've mentioned, because it can be done without a password.

```
#!/bin/sh
touch db.backup.sql.gz
chmod 600 db.backup.sql.gz
mysqldump -u nonprivuser --password="pass" --all-databases --single-transaction | gzip > db.backup.sql.gz
gpg -e -r your@email.com db.backup.sql.gz && rm -f db.backup.sql.gz
s3put backup/db.backup.sql.gz.gpg db.backup.sql.gz.gpg
```

Comment: added a short example script for you

Comment: Good to go I think.

Answer (score 0):

Using a password inside the script is a really bad idea as this can be seen in `ps aux` and read out by every system user.

I would suggest you to look into [mysqldump-secure](https://github.com/cytopia/mysqldump-secure). This is a shell script that does `openssl` encryption based on public-private key encryption and is a lot more performant than gpg.

Answer (score -1):

You can also just use RDS which does all of this for you.